# Flutter firebase cloud function, playload issue

Tags: android, dart, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using firebase cloud function for send push notification. It works but issue by default it shows badge and does not play sound when notification comes.

Below is my playload code.

```
        var playload = {
            notification: {
                title: msgData.title,
                body: msgData.message,
                sound: 'default',
                badge: '0',
                click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
            }, 
            data: {
                title: msgData.title,
                body: msgData.message,
                sound: 'default',
                badge: '0',
                click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
            }               
        }
        var options = {
            priority: "high",
            timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24
          };
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, playload, options).then((response) => {
            console.log('Sent to all the devices');
            return response;
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            return 0;
        })
```

I have set **'sound': 'default'** and **badge: '0'** but doesn't help me.

**UPDATED:**

I have tried with double quote for both keys and values but didn't work yet.

```
        var playload = {
            "notification": {
                "title": msgData.title,
                "body": msgData.message,
                "sound": "default",
                "badge": "0",
                "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"
            },
            "data": {
                "title": msgData.title,
                "body": msgData.message,
                "sound": "default",
                "badge": "0",
                "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"
            }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe are you experincing [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26005)? I've supposed this happens on Android, due to your question tag.

Comment: Although I want to set badge 0, I don't want to set custom sound.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to replace your single quotes with double quotes?

From [JSON.org](https://json.org):

> A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or
>   false or null, or an object or an array. These structures can be
>   nested.

The title and the body of your message is processed before it eventually will fail which might be why it seems that your formatting is okay.

Let me know whether this has helped you.

Comment: As you did comment before I have tried at same time but didn't help me. Just curious why it's not working? Kindly check updated question.